# Can't get my SQL query to comply with date request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Query....

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.ProductID, p.ProductName, 
    od.Quantity, o.Shipcountry, o.ShippedDate
FROM 
    Products p, [Order Details] od, Orders o
WHERE  
    p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    AND od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    AND o.ShippedDate < '1997-01-01'
    AND ShipCountry = 'Spain'
     OR ShipCountry = 'Portugal'
ORDER BY 
    p.ProductName ASC
```

I am trying to get all orders that shipped BEFORE the date entered, yet it doesn't seem to be working...at all, below are a couple results from the query

```
82  Alice Mutton    91  Portugal    1996-10-17 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    110 Portugal    1997-03-04 00:00:00.000
17  Alice Mutton    21  Portugal    1996-11-18 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    4   Portugal    1997-03-04 00:00:00.000
17  Alice Mutton    28  Portugal    1998-04-13 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    130 Portugal    1997-04-08 00:00:00.000
17  Alice Mutton    10  Portugal    1996-10-25 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    22  Portugal    1996-10-25 00:00:00.000
17  Alice Mutton    1   Portugal    1997-06-06 00:00:00.000
17  Alice Mutton    36  Portugal    1998-03-26 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    49  Portugal    1997-01-02 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    66  Portugal    1997-07-29 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    39  Portugal    1997-01-02 00:00:00.000
82  Alice Mutton    120 Portugal    1997-04-08 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL yet you are using square braces, which are indicative of SQL Server or Sybase.  Which database are you really using?

Comment: My fualt...its SQL Server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OR` statement is messing up your results in your `WHERE` criteria.  You can solve it with `IN` or using parentheses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, od.Quantity,o.Shipcountry,o.ShippedDate
FROM Products p 
   JOIN [Order Details] od ON p.ProductID=od.ProductID
   JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
WHERE o.ShippedDate<'1997-01-01'
   AND o.ShipCountry IN ('Spain','Portugal')
ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC
```

If you'd prefer to use parentheses, then this would be the equivalent to using `IN`:

```
...
    AND (ShipCountry = 'Spain' OR ShipCountry = 'Portugal')
...
```

Comment: @Jeremy -- np, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `or` statement.  But, you should rewrite the query using explicit joins.  Also, `IN` will help fix the problem with the `or`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, od.Quantity,o.Shipcountry,o.ShippedDate
FROM Products p JOIN
     [Order Details] od
     ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID IN
     Orders o
     ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
WHERE o.ShippedDate<'1997-01-01' AND
     ShipCountry IN ('Spain', 'Portugal')
ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mysql order of operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), `AND` takes precedence over `OR` so use parentheses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, od.Quantity,o.Shipcountry,o.ShippedDate
FROM Products p, [Order Details] od, Orders o
WHERE  p.ProductID=od.ProductID
   AND od.OrderID=o.OrderID
   AND o.ShippedDate<'1997-01-01'
   AND (ShipCountry = 'Spain' OR ShipCountry = 'Portugal')
ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC
```

I hope that helps; if not, do leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use date_format() or date() when you comparing datetime

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, od.Quantity,o.Shipcountry,o.ShippedDate
    FROM Products p 
       JOIN [Order Details] od ON p.ProductID=od.ProductID
       JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(o.ShippedDate, "%Y-%m-%d") < '1997-01-01'
       AND o.ShipCountry IN ('Spain','Portugal')
    ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC
```